# round up datetime using joda library

Tags: java, jodatime

I am looking for a way to round up a datetime value using Joda time library.
I need to do this only if the interval is within 60 seconds to the next rounded hour.

For example to round up:

```
10/1/2012 10:59:00 => 10/1/2012 11:00:00
10/1/2012 10:59:01 => 10/1/2012 11:00:00
10/1/2012 10:59:59 => 10/1/2012 11:00:00
10/1/2012 10:49:59 => 10/1/2012 10:49:59 (no rounding needed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `base` datetime you have to trunc to hours. Lets call the result of this operation as `product`. Then add to product one hour. After that you need to substract the product with `base` (product - base) that will give `difference`.

if difference is less then 61 seconds you set product, otherwise you leave the base.

edit:

Or you could just check that your date has 59 minutest and add one minutes to it and set

```
if(dateTime.getMinuteOfHour() == 59) {
  dateTime.addMinutes(1);
  dateTime.setSecondOfMinute(0);
  dateTime.setMillisOfSecond(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something in the lines of the following snippet:

```
DateTime input = new DateTime(2012, 10, 04, 21, 39, 0, 0);
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
long diffInSeconds =
    dateTime.minus(input.getMillis()).getMillis() / 1000;
if (diffInSeconds <= 60)
{
    input = input.plus(diffInSeconds * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do it :

```
DateTime round = new DateTime().withTime(23, 59, 0, 0)

DateTime temp = round.plusMinutes(1);
if(temp.getHourOfDay()!=round.getHourOfDay())
    round = new DateTime(temp.withTime(temp.getHourOfDay(),0,0,0));
```